# Creating Folder sharing Reference

Tags: windows, windows-8, shared-folders

I want to set up 2 folders in separate locations such that any file changes and edits within one folder occur within the other as well using Windows 8.1

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Another solution is to create a batch file which when double clicked copies everything (Except itself) into the opposite directory. But I am hoping for something more natural than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a junction point. They act like links do for files. This will make the two folders actually point to the same location. This is done with the MKLINK command:

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file symbolic link.
       /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J   Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.
```

The specific command you want is:

```
MKLINK /J folderB folderA
```

Where folderA is the folder you want to have two copies of and folderB is the location you want the second copy of it.

Comment: So this is a one-time command? after which the changes will be automatic?